# How do I get WebStorm's JavaScript Library support using DefinitelyTyped interface definitions to work?

Tags: javascript, reference, webstorm, definitelytyped

I'm trying to get WebStorm's JavaScript Library support using **DefinitelyTyped** TypeScript interface definitions to work as expected (hopefully as intended) in JavaScript.

I've added the library definitions using the Download feature...
[image: Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries]
*I made sure it's in the global scope, too.*

Yet I can't seem to reference THREE or any of the other DefinitelyTyped library module definitions.
[image: Unresolved variable or type 'THREE' ...]
*It's not just undefined inside of JSDoc references, it's undefined everywhere. I know I should have "@type" here instead of "@param", I was just trying to elicit a different result; the results are the same.*

**What am I doing wrong?**
Do I need to create a `_references.js` as one would for Visual Studio or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart WebStorm **at least twice** (possibly four times) after having added the interface definitions.

[image]

This solution applies to WebStorm 2016.2.1